# How to check whether a JSON object key is an object or string?

Tags: javascript

So right now, I created an example of a JSON object where:

```
var myObj = {
    address: {
        0: ["41 Lake Avenue"]
    },
    name: "jake"
}
```

myObj itself as a whole is a JSON object, and inside it, I have two keys which are address and name respectively. So the value of the **address key** is also an **Object** since its in braces, where as the **name** **key** value is just a **string**.

I want to write a simple check in **javascript** to **check** whether or not the **keys** in **myObj** is an **object** or a **string**. So if its **an object**, it returns **true** where as if its **not an object** it returns **false**. Therefore for address, it would be true while for name, it would be false.

I tried looking around for some isObject() method similar to isArray() but apparently i couldn't find so I'd like some help on this so i wrote a pseudocode below for the logic:

```
for (i=0;i<2;i++) {
   if myObj[i] is Object {
      return true;}
   else{
      return false;}
}
```

Comment: you can use `typeof` to check whether its string or not.

Comment: I'm new here and rarely program in JS but wtf are these comments and answers. You did the entire thing wrong. Use for in

    `for (k in myObj) { console.log(typeof(myObj[k]) == 'string'); }`

Comment: The typeof operator returns a string indicating the type of the unevaluated operand:

    ```for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(myObj))  { if( value && typeof value =='object'){return true;} else{ return false;}}```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `typeof`.

Note: The question is not clear and does not explains what will happen if there multiple keys with value as an object. Since the below function will return as soon as it comes across a key whose value is a object

```js
var myObj = {
  address: {
    0: ["41 Lake Avenue"]
  },
  name: "jake"
}


function isObject(obj) {
  for (let keys in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[keys] === 'object' && obj[keys] !== null) {
      return true
    }
  }
}

console.log(isObject(myObj))
```

Comment: I think using 
`for (let [key,value] of Object.entries(myObj))`
will be better since he gets to have the property name.
[example here](https://repl.it/join/ygtnhjwo-dochan)

Comment: maybe also a `return false` after the for loop ;) ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the typeof(var) operator :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

For object:

```
typeof yourVariable === 'object' && yourVariable !== null
```

For string:

```
typeof yourVariable === 'string'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (typeof varible === 'object') {
    // is object
}
```

But Null is also recognized as object. So you could also proove that.